# Installing twisted on python 3.5 and virtualenv using pip

Tags: python

when i run

```
pip install twisted
```

in the command line in windows, it starts installing packages until the flowing line comes up.

```
failed building wheel for twisted
```

pip then crashed soon after, saying it has failed the installation.

why is this ?

is there a way round it to install twisted?

my wheel version is 0.29, I'm running windows 10, twisted installs fine for python 2.7

thanks

Comment: As far as I know, twisted isn't supported on python3 yet. There are still 31 issues active for the Python 3 milestone: https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/query?status=assigned&status=new&status=reopened&group=status&milestone=Python-3.x

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a solution to this (I use Python 3.6.1). Found this page:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

It contains the windows binaries for a large number of python packages. For python 3.5 use the version with 'cp35' in the filename, and choose win32/amd64 based on your installation. You can install the .whl file easily using pip:

```
pip install Twisted‑17.1.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl
```

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error too and in my case, the problem seemed to be that I did not have the Python workflow enabled in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. To enable that, launch the Visual Studio Launcher > Modify > tick the workflows you want to use (i.e. Python). This rectified it for me.