# Installing Twisted wheel on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, python, pip

I am trying to install Scrapy on Windows 7. Thanks to problems with the installation, I got to installing Twisted first. 
If i try

```
pip install twisted
```

I get "failed building wheel for Twisted". 
Is I came across suggestions: [Installing twisted on python 3.5 and virtualenv using pip](https://superuser.com/questions/1179925/installing-twisted-on-python-3-5-and-virtualenv-using-pip)
I downloaded the file **Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl** and I would like to install Twisted via this wheel. How should I modify this command, so pip finds the file. Or where should I place the file?

```
pip install Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I tried:

```
pip install twisted --no-index --find-links C:\Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get a response: 'URL "C:\Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" is ignored. It is either a non-existing path or lacks a specific scheme'. 
If I try:

```
pip install Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl --no-index --find-links C:\Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

I get a response: Requirement 'Twisted.[..] looks like a filename, but the file does not exist'.
The path is correct, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turn on file extension displaying and double-check the extension of the downloaded file.

Comment: I got file extensions displayed as standard, the filename is correct.

Comment: What does `python -c "import os; print(os.path.isfile(r'C:\Twisted-18.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'))"` return?

Answer (score 0):

you can install it with python -m pip install Twisted-19.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl , change the package name as per your version.